# How to run linux command from rancher UI upgrade 'mkdir test_parvez'

Tags: rancher

I want to create a directory on rancher container when upgrading container.I added linux command on rancher UI upgrade command tab 'mkdir test_parvez', but i am getting mkdir: cannot create directory 'test_parvez': File exists

Answer (score 0):

It almost seems that directory already exists.  You may want to use the command `mkdir -p test_parvez` so it won't error when it already exists.  If you need the directory to be empty you could remove it before creating it with this: `rm -rf test_parvez && mkdir -p test_parvez` (this may be preferred because there is a chance that path refers to a file and it, therefore, cannot overwrite a file to be a directory).

Also, I strongly recommend using complete paths.  You may already be using a complete path but simplified it for this question.